# Why is this navigation bar not centering?

Tags: html, css

I noticed the navigation `li` items (yellow section) were right of center, so I altered the containing `div`/`nav` widths and background background colors just so I could see what was going on in an attempt to fix the misalignment; however, I can't seem to see a reason why this is occurring (in about 6 browsers).

Here is problematic markup/css: http://building-more.site50.net/

It seems to work fine in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cTXXH/1/

It doesn't seem to display at all in IE, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

It's because some of the elements already have default values such as padding and marging that are skewing your positionings, and this could be different for each browser. That's why people often 'reset' CSS to use 0 margins and 0 paddings by default instead, before starting with their own styles.

Your example works fine in your Fiddle because 'normalize CSS' is checked. This is a framework similar to CSS resets which can be found here: http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/ - it makes sure that your default positionings are consistent between browsers, and gives you a clean slate to work with.

If you were to include it into your web page it would solve your issues. Hope that helps.

Comment: I included the normalize CSS with no success. I read through the documentation, tried linking it and just including it in my own CSS file; is there something else that I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Also, it looks like you forgot the ending bracket in your endif statement for the IE check.

Should be:

```
<![endif]-->
```